# TypeScript Generic of Type this

Tags: javascript, typescript

Why is TypeScript (2.1.0) complaining about the following code?

```
import Request from "../request/request.ts";
export default class Machine{
  private id: number;
  private url:string;
  private make:string;
  private model:string;
  private request:any;
  constructor(){
    var self = this;
    this.request = new Request<self>(this.url); //cannot find name self
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line of your code (changed from `self` to `this`):

```
this.request = new Request<this>(this.url);
```

Have two different meanings for the `this` keyword:

1. The actual reference to `this` at runtime (`this.request` and `this.url`)
2. Specifying of the type of `this` for compilation (`new Request<this>`)

You mixed the two meanings and that's why it does not work, if you want to use the `self` instead of `this` then you'll need to do use `typeof`:

```
this.request = new Request<typeof self>(this.url);
```

Comment: is it a bug that the compiler doesn't infer self's type?  is there a reason why it shouldn't?

Comment: No, it's not a bug, `self` is a variable but what you put as generic type should be a type so it doesn't work, but `typeof self` works.